# Convert curl to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I try below curl using terminal is working well and it return a string Ok or fail.

```
curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"username","password":"password"}' https://123.123.123.123:1234/session
```

When i try convert to it not work.

```
    <?php
$data = array( "username" => "username", "password" => "password" );

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init( "https://123.123.123.123:1234/apicall" ); curl_setopt_array( $ch, array( CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)) ), CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true ));

$result = curl_exec( $ch ); //Make it all happen and store response

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`curlopt_postfields` accepts an array, so you don't need to `json_encode` the data array:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
```

See more info on [curlopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) options:

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like
>   'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key
>   and field data as value.

You also had one too many closing parentheses in your example and you weren't closing the connection. Full code:

```
<?php
$data = array("username" => "username", "password" => "password");

$ch = curl_init("https://123.123.123.123:1234/apicall");
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: should change 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string) and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string